# Error PRI175: 0xdef00502 - Processing Resources and error : PRI224: 0xdef00502 - root node not found

Tags: c#, uwp

I have the two errors, and I totally have no idea how to solve them, I have already tried everything, please help!

C:\Praca\Projekty\client-windows\Project\Project.csproj" (Build;BuiltProjectOutputGroup;BuiltProjectOutputGroupDependencies;DebugSymbolsProjectOutputGroup;DebugSymbolsProjectOutputGroupDependencies;DocumentationProjectOutputGroup;DocumentationProjectOutputGroupDependencies;SatelliteDllsProjectOutputGroup;SatelliteDllsProjectOutputGroupDependencies;SGenFilesOutputGroup;SGenFilesOutputGroupDependencies target) (1) ->

2>(_GenerateProjectPriFileCore target) ->

2>  GENERATEPROJECTPRIFILE : error : PRI175: 0xdef00502 - Processing Resources

2>  GENERATEPROJECTPRIFILE : error : PRI224: 0xdef00502 - root node not found.

Comment: Hello, please check your xaml file for syntax errors, such as missing closing tags. If the editor does not give a clear prompt, can you provide a minimal reproducible demo, which will help us analyze your problem

Answer (score 5):

The problem was with ".resw" files. During the merger, I took all the changes from the master and the branch. And this caused an error, I replaced these files with old ones that were in the branch.

It helped me solve this problem.

Comment: ot duwi bratooha